# MySQL total row size or equivelant of SELECT LENGTH(*) FROM table WHERE id='1';

Tags: mysql

This as straight-forward as the idea gets but naturally it does not work...

```
SELECT LENGTH(*) FROM table WHERE id='1';
```

Is there a way to DYNAMICALLY have MySQL return the length of all the combined columns for a row without having to manually specify each and every column like so?

```
SELECT LENGTH(column1), LENGTH(column2) FROM table WHERE id='1';
```

Comment: It wouldn't make much sense for that to work since `LENGTH` is for measuring strings, and not all columns are strings. It doesn't make much sense for you to compare `id`, which is likely an integer, to the string `'1'` either. Even if a `LENGTH(*)` existed, why would you want to know it? That doesn't tell you anything about how much storage space the row is using, for example.

Comment: It tells me about the amount of space an email is using for example and that's important when I've got to manually back up databases on a regular basis.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to know it for calculating row size, take a look at AVG_ROW_LENGTH in information_schema tables. Reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/tables-table.html

Comment: I don't want an average length of multiple rows, I need the total length (regardless of text/binary) of a given row. Doing a quick search I can't find anything in regards to `AVG_ROW_LENGTH` that would allow me to do that.